# Simple Oracle Procedure returning boolean

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to write a simple procedure that returns a boolean value . I have written a procedure as below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procOneINOUTParameter( )
return  boolean
IS
BEGIN

  return true;

END;
```

But running this scripts gives me the following error .

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   current delete exists prior
```

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: PL/SQL syntax does not recognise `()`. If you have no parameters just omit the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

A procedure does not have a return value; only a function can have a return value.
You're trying to create a procedure that returns a value, which is opposite to the idea of procedure; if you need a return value from a procedure, use OUT parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function procOneINOUTParameter
return  boolean
IS
BEGIN

  return true;

END;
```